# Offline Installer / Fixed Version Installer for WebView2 Runtime

Tags: microsoft-edge, webview2

The road map seems rather intransparent to me. Is this planned? Is there any info on a potential release date? We require to use WebView2 on machines that aren't necessarily connected to the internet. The full browser would not be needed, which is why the idea of [WebView2 Runtime](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) seems like the way to go. As of right now however the installer needs to connect to the internet.

Comment: Currently it requires the Canary build, which is probably why it requires an internet connection. I assume that once it can use the standard Edge version, this requirement might go away

Answer (score 4):

I work on the WebView2 project. The installer you linked to is actually the standalone evergreen installer that can be used entirely offline :). If the device is online, the installed runtime will try to update itself, but offline it works fine too just not getting any updates. If you run a later version of the installer when a older version is already installed, the installer will update the version of WebView2 Runtime on the device (this is basically how you can update the evergreen runtime offline). Right now the Runtime and installer are under preview and we strongly advise against redistributing it outside your org/company. We are targeting Q4 this year for GA.

Fixed version is not out for preview yet. You can find our roadmap with dates on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/roadmap.

Comment: Hello, do I still need to install the WebView2 Runtime for my app or is it now included with windows ? It doesn't show in the windows installer prerequesites in visual studio 19, this is a mess just to use a webview. Any help tip please ?